# AWS Lambda sending HTTP request

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

This is likely a question with an easy answer, but i can't seem to figure it out.

Background: I have a python Lambda function to pick up changes in a DB, then using HTTP post the changes in json to a URL. I'm using urllib2 sort of like this:

```
# this runs inside a loop, in reality my error handling is much better
request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.add_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request, json_message)
except:
    response = "Failed!"
```

It seems from the logs either the call to send the messages is skipped entirely, or times-out while waiting for a response.

Is there a permission setting I'm missing, the outbound rules in AWS appear to be right. [Edit] - The VPC applied to this lambda does have internet access, and the security groups applied appear to allow internet access. [/Edit]

I've tested the code locally (connected to the same data source) and it works flawlessly.

It appears the other questions related to posting from a lambda is related to node.js, and usually because the url is wrong. In this case, I'm using a requestb.in url, that i know is working as it works when running locally.

Edit:

I've setup my NAT gateway, and it should work, I've even gone as far as going to a different AWS account, re-creating the conditions, and it works fine. I can't see any Security Groups that would be blocking access anywhere. It's continuing to time-out.

Edit:
Turns out i was just an idiot when i setup my default route to the NAT Gateway, out of habit i wrote 0.0.0.0/24 instead of 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: Your Lambda function is configured to run inside your VPC? Is it configured to execute inside a public subnet or a private subnet?

Comment: I've got 4 subnets applied, all of which have internet access. It can access other resources inside the VPC/subnet fine, as that's where the DB is.

Comment: Are all 4 subnets public subnets? Or are any of them private?

Comment: They're private, but I have setup a gateway for them to have access (I've got other EC2 machines on the subnet that access the internet fine)

Comment: Do you have a security group on your NAT that's possibly blocking access from your Lambda functions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you've deployed your Lambda function inside your VPC, it does not obtain a public IP address, even if it's deployed into a subnet with a route to an Internet Gateway.  It only obtains a private IP address, and thus can not communicate to the public Internet by itself.

To communicate to the public Internet, Lambda functions deployed inside your VPC need to be done so in a private subnet which has a [route](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Route_Tables.html#route-tables-nat) to either a [NAT Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-nat-network-address-translation-gateway-for-aws/) or a self-managed [NAT instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html).

Comment: I've setup a NAT Gateway, and it's still unable to access the internet. I now have it running on a private subnet that has a route to a nat gateway on a public subnet (routed though an igw).

Comment: What sort of VPC are you using--one generated from the Management Console's VPC WIzard (e.g. "VPC with Public and Private Subnets"), or a custom one?  Did you set it up, or someone else? The only other part of a VPC that could be blocking the access that hasn't been mentioned yet is the network ACL (NACL).  By default they're usually fully permissive, but if this is a pre-existing or custom VPC, a NACL may need to be modified as well.

Comment: It was a stupid route issue on my part, muscle memory of typing /24 after IPs caused my default route to break, totally my bad.

Comment: I did the same thing, Steve, created a bunch of private subnets with the /x and then misconfigured the route.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue. I overcame it by using boto3 to invoke a lambda from another lambda.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')

response = client.invoke(
    FunctionName='string',
    InvocationType='Event'|'RequestResponse'|'DryRun',
    LogType='None'|'Tail',
    ClientContext='string',
    Payload=b'bytes'|file,
    Qualifier='string'
)
```

But make sure that you set the IAM policy for lambda role (in the Source AWS account) to invoke that another lambda.

Adding to the above, boto3 uses HTTP at the backend.